# Look up the matching element from another data frame and return its id- python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

i have a orders dataframe:

| items | chat_id |
| --- | --- |
| curd,vada,rice | 74374374h4473 |
| idly,sambar | 7949759459h34 |

I have another unique menu items data frame with its own particular id:

| id | items |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | idly |
| 2 | vada |
| 3 | rice |
| 4 | curd |
| 5 | sambar |

now I want to match the elements and return its id's by printing its chat_id in the orders data frame

| chat_id | id |
| --- | --- |
| 74374374h4473 | 4 |
| 74374374h4473 | 2 |
| 74374374h4473 | 3 |
| 7949759459h34 | 1 |
| 7949759459h34 | 5 |

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your question and change unique menu items data frame to a table format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id you have dataframe `df_orders`:

```
            items        chat_id
0  curd,vada,rice  74374374h4473
1     idly,sambar  7949759459h34
```

and dataframe `df_menu`:

```
   id   items
0   1    idly
1   2    vada
2   3    rice
3   4    curd
4   5  sambar
```

Then:

```
df_orders["items"] = df_orders["items"].str.split(",")
df_orders = df_orders.explode("items")
print(df_orders.merge(df_menu, on="items")[["chat_id", "id"]])
```

Prints:

```
         chat_id  id
0  74374374h4473   4
1  74374374h4473   2
2  74374374h4473   3
3  7949759459h34   1
4  7949759459h34   5
```